# How to add legends to a geom_line() function in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I´m trying to set legends to two lines in my graph in order to people recognize what represents each line, but I don't know how

Here's a code example

```
x <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
y <- (6:10)
z <- (1:5)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=z, y=x), color="black") + 
  geom_line(aes(x=z, y=y), color="red")
```

[image]

I would like to watch legends like the next graph in the part of "Periodo"

[image]

I DON'T want to categorized my data by another vector, as follows:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=z, y=x, color="categoria"))
```

Comment: Could [this answer](https://community.rstudio.com/t/adding-manual-legend-to-ggplot2/41651/3) be what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack all variables you want to display into a single column, and use their names as color labels.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(c(x, y), names_to = "catogory") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = z, y = value, color = catogory))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=z, y=x, color= "X")) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=z, y=y, color="Y")) +
  labs(color = "X_Y")
```

[image]

Comment: If there are 100 columns to display in the plot, this method needs to hard-code `geom_line(aes(x=z, y=..., color="..."))` for  100 times.